# How can I improve this update script?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I want to update a table in oracle which has 155.750 rows.
I write this:

```
 UPDATE Table1 R
SET R.TOTAL = 
(SELECT SUM(T.TOTALS_TO_DATE)
FROM Table2 T
WHERE T.ID= R.ID
AND T.TYPE = 'type5');
```

Table1 has index at `ID` 
Table2 has indexes at `ID` and `TYPE`.
This is not responding. How can edit this to run fastly?

If I write this select it runs fastly.

```
 SELECT SUM(T.TOTALS_TO_DATE),R.ID
    FROM Table2 T,Table1 R
    WHERE T.ID= R.ID
    AND T.TYPE = 'type5' 
  group by R.ID ;
```

This runs but I do not understand why the update script takes 3000seconds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `MERGE` statement

```
MERGE INTO table1 R using
( SELECT SUM(T.TOTALS_TO_DATE) S, T.ID
    FROM Table2 T
    WHERE T.TYPE = 'type5' 
  group by T.ID 
) T
ON ( R.ID = T.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET R.TOTAL = T.S
;
```

Comment: it works fastly  I want to sure about it runs correctly? thanks for answer

Comment: it is the same with update? so why this is so fast :) I need to know it is same with update script I investigate records. And merge statament is only for oracle? thanks

Comment: @user1716182 in the update statment the subquery for sum calculation is executed for earch row (155.750 times). In the MERGE statement the subquery will be executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the `where` condition in the Update script. Hence it is updating the whole table1 and hence it is taking time.

For the `select` query you  have mentioned the `where` clause which is running faster.

Edit:-

Check our this [link](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/AhmadOsama/personal/450/sql-server-optimizing-update-queries-for-large-data-volumes)

Here are some of the steps which you can do to improve your update command run faster.

1. Removing index on the column to be updated.
2. Executing the update in smaller batches.
3. Disabling Delete triggers.
4. Replacing Update statement with a Bulk-Insert operation.

Comment: Thanks for answering but ı put the where clause in update script in select query? how can  change that

Comment: Do you have to update all the rows in the column TOTAL of your table without any condition?

Comment: yes I want to update each row, but when I write select it returns in 1 sec with all datas.

Comment: Updated my answer. This approach is for updating the column which has huge volume of data

Comment: I do not have index about updated column already, and I don not have delete triggers. I will try other solutions which you talk about

Comment: Sure...And do follow that link which I mentioned. It will surely help you.:)